# plotting a python function that uses an array

Tags: sage

In sagemath, I would like to plot the following function `foo` (`Coef` is an array that is big enough) :

```
    def foo(x):
        x_approx = floor (x*4)
        return Coef[x_approx]
```

I wanted to use the command `plot(foo(x), (x,0,0.1))`.

But I got the error `unable to convert floor(4*x) to an integer`.

Whereas when `foo is not using an array, it works:

```
    def foo(x):
        x_approx = floor (x*4)
        return 4*x_approx
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `plot(foo, (x, 0, 0.1))` instead (that is, replace `foo(x)` with `foo`). If you use `foo(x)`, then Sage tries to evaluate `foo(x)` first, in which case it treats `x` as a symbolic variable and can't turn it into a number to plot. If you use `foo`, then it knows to treat it as a plottable/callable function, and it does the right thing.

Edit: I think the issue is that for plotting, Sage requires a certain type of function, a symbolic function, and using a Python construct like `Coef[...]` doesn't fit into that framework.

Comment: Thx ! you make my day ;)